# How to get all records of object since specific date?

Tags: query, simple-salesforce

I'm using Python with simple-salesforce package.

Eventually I'm running queries like:

```
make_query("SELECT Id, Email, Name, Title  FROM Contact")
```

What I want to do is getting all records of the object that were added/deleted/modified since TIMESTAMP X

Should be something like:

```
SELECT Id, Email, Name, Title  FROM Contact WHERE date_updated>= TIMESTAMP '2020-02-05 09:54:22.070144'
```

How can this be done in SalesForce query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, you need to set your datetime to SOQL in this format:

```
SELECT Id, Email, Name, Title  FROM Contact WHERE SystemModStamp >= 2020-02-05T09:54:22Z ALL ROWS
```

Note, that there are no quotes.

UPDATE:

If you need to track updates made with automated processes, too (https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000336532&language=en_US&type=1&mode=1) replace **LastModifiedDate** with **SystemModStamp**.

To track delete records: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000BIZ4IAO

UPDATE: (ALL ROWS and IsDeleted explanation)

ALL ROWS modifier allows you to query both existing and deleted records (that are left in recycle bin). Assume you have 5 accounts and 3 accounts you have deleted previously.

`SELECT Id FROM Account ALL ROWS` will give you 8 records, whereas `SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE IsDeleted = true ALL ROWS` will give you only that 3 records that are placed in recycle bin.

Also, these 2 queries are equivalent, they will return 5 existing rows:

`SELECT Id FROM Account`

`SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE IsDeleted = false ALL ROWS`

UPDATE:

If you are getting:

> MALFORMED_QUERY: ALL ROWS not allowed in this context

Try to use **queryAll()** through your connection:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_queryall.htm

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104097/discussion-on-answer-by-mariia-illarionova-how-to-get-all-records-of-object-sinc).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can write the SOQL with Date and DateTime with where condition. I would suggest please read the [documentation of Date and Datetime format](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm), In this format, you can see lot of date/DateTime format.

You can also use Date literals accordingly to your need, please go through the documentation.

Example:
[image]

SOQL Example with a datetime value

```
SELECT Id
FROM Account
WHERE CreatedDate > 2005-10-08T01:02:03Z
```

Answer (score 0):

### Answer for 2023

With Python and  [simple_salesforce](https://github.com/simple-salesforce/simple-salesforce), use the following:

```python
import simple_salesforce

# This example uses security token authorization
sf = simple_salesforce.Salesforce(
    username=[USERNAME],
    password=[PASSWORD],
    security_token=[SECURITY_TOKEN],
)

# Make sure to format your timestamp correctly
# '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ'
timestamp = [YOUR_TIMESTAMP]
query = f"""
select      Id
            , Email
            , Name
            , Title
from        Contact
where       SystemModstamp >= {timestamp}
"""

response = sf.query_all(query, include_deleted=True)
```

**A few things to note:**

- The SystemModstamp field can be leveraged as a catch-all for most recent create/update/delete for a given record. [According to Salesforce](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000387261&type=1):

> 'SystemModstamp' is the date and time when a record was last modified by a User or by an automated process (such as a trigger.)

- The `ALL ROWS` keyword will not work with simple_salesforce query methods, even though [it is the standard way](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_query_all_rows.htm) which you would get deleted (and archived) records from Salesforce using a SOQL query. According to every Salesforce forum post I've found, "It's not currently available with the API." If you include it in your query, it will raise the following error:

> MALFORMED_QUERY: ALL ROWS not allowed in this context

- The [`query_all()` function in simple_salesforce](https://github.com/simple-salesforce/simple-salesforce/blob/6e0ab819afed6680b90edf993370ad22bb5bce24/simple_salesforce/api.py#L510) does NOT behave the same as the [`query_all()` function in the API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_queryall.htm). Rather, it is "a convenience wrapper around `query()` and `query_more()`". This can be very confusing, for sure.
- [Under the hood](https://github.com/simple-salesforce/simple-salesforce/blob/6e0ab819afed6680b90edf993370ad22bb5bce24/simple_salesforce/api.py#L447), `include_deleted=True` changes the behavior of `query_all()` in simple_salesforce to pass `'queryAll/'` to the request url instead of the default behavior which is to pass `'query/'`. This means you will get all records regardless of whether they are deleted* and/or archived** or not. If you need to filter one of these categories out, that can be done in the query's where-clause (`IsArchived = false`, `IsDeleted = true`, etc)

  - *By "deleted", I mean records which are currently in the "Recycle Bin" in Salesforce. These records stay in the Recycle Bin for 15 days (unless [otherwise extended](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000387160&type=1)) before they are permanently deleted by Salesforce. If there is some method by which records can be retrieved after being permanently deleted, I am not familiar with it.
  - **By ["archived"](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_guidelines_archive.htm), I mean records for Activity (i.e. Task, Event) which are automatically archived by Salesforce. These remain accessible indefinitely unless otherwise deleted.
- Passing `include_deleted=True` to `sf.query_all()` can potentially increase the amount of records scanned (particularly with Activity records which can be archived), so applying a filter to narrow your query will help with speed. Filtering date fields helps Salesforce be efficient in such a case.

*Disclaimer: I can verify that this works in my environment:*

- *Python 3.7.3*
- *simple_salesforce 1.12.3*